# MediaElement.js overlay button

Tags: mediaelement.js

I am using MediaElement.js to build my own HTML5 video player over Youtube videos.  I am currently just using the MediaElement object, without the MediaElementPlayer library.  I was wondering if there was any way I could get the overlay start button (or emulate it) with just the object.

For an example of the overlay I am talking about, I mean the white arrow with the circle around it here: http://mediaelementjs.com/examples/?name=youtube

Comment: I'm also looking for this, will let you know if I find it